# Imagemagick : zoom picture until fits DIN A4 dimensions

Tags: imagemagick, zooming, imagemagick-convert

I need to process some pictures with imagemagick. Those pictures have different proportions and sizes. My goal is to 'zoom' every picture so at the end i'll have a whole DIN-A4 printable surface. Which could be the best approach ? I'm thinking of doing something like this:

---

[image: fitting image to din a-4]

**A** : I would expand original picture to fit 'DIN A4' height.

**B** : I would expand A picture to fit 'DIN A-4' width.

**C** : Final picture has the same aspect ratio and was 'zoomed'

A real example. Pay attention how the butterfly's image is bigger ( zoomed ) in the second one. ( using 'Canon Image Garden software' , print > option without borders' ):

LEFT IMAGE Original file.
CENTER IMAGE: how it would look printed covering whole a DIN A4 sheet.
RIGHT IMAGE: This is how we'll see the original image printed

[image]

---

I have no idea how could i do this using imagemagick. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To resize an image to A4 size (595 x 842) in ImageMagick, use

```
convert image -resize 595x842 -background white -gravity center -extent 595x843 result
```

Comment: Sorry but in this case i need to scale the image zooming it to cover whole the din a4 sheet dimensions. Your solution only resizes the image. If you look at the 'C' final step the initial image is bigger ( i loose part of the image information, no problem in my case )

Comment: I do not understand what you want. Perhaps just `convert image -resize 595x842 result`. That will resize to fill height and keep the aspect ratio for portrait mode images.

Comment: Can you show me an input and your desired output actual images?

Comment: I updated with another example ( i think it'll clarify my goal )

Comment: Is the left the input and the right the output? If so, you have cropped the right image as it does not show everything that is on the left image. The two images do not have the same aspect ratio, also. Can you post images separately, so I can see the dimensions of both and test with them

Comment: Left raw image, right processed image and how it will look printed on a sheet because it has the same dimensions. It doesn't matter if the final image loose part of the initial image. I just only want to 'zoom' ( scale ? )  the initial image to cover the whole final din-a4 sheet.

Comment: `convert image -resize 595x842^ -gravity center -extent 595x843 result`

Comment: Awesome! thats what i wanted. I appreciate your help :-)